# autosuggestion with multiple field

Tags: javascript

i need to implement an auto suggestion feature in my website and i need some java script framework or code that should be easily developed or edited and the autosuggest will be multiple field

Answer (score 2):

Adapt the jQuery one: http://jqueryui.com/

Answer (score 0):

Autocompleter with mootools.

http://digitarald.de/project/autocompleter/